# Angular UI Grid reloading cell templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I can't figure out how to do what's supposed to be very simple.

I have 10 columns in my UI grid, they are all editable.  My objective is dynamically "**disable**" or have them be "**required**" inputs, depending on the options of a scope object.

The object:

```
$scope.columnOptions = {
    'column1': 'MANDATORY',
    'column2': 'DISABLED'....
}
```

The cell templates

```
cellTemplate: '<input ng-disabled="{{ grid.appScope.columnOptions.column1=== \'DISABLED\' }}" ' +
                'ng-required="{{ grid.appScope.columnOptions.column1=== \'MANDATORY\' }}" ' +
                'data-ng-model="row.entity.column1" style="width:95%">'
```

This works if the object exists upon initialization.

**The problem is that when I change the value of columnOptions, the rows don't get updated.**

I have tried different ui-grid APIs to reload my template but it did not work:

```
        $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
        $scope.gridApi.core.raise.reloadData();
        $scope.gridApi.core.refreshRows();
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange('all');
```

I've added a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3bIrtJuwHNrTeltIPAXw?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell templates are not correct:

```
cellTemplate: '<input ng-disabled="grid.appScope.columnOptions.column1=== \'DISABLED\'" ' +
            'ng-required="grid.appScope.columnOptions.column1=== \'MANDATORY\' " ' +
            'data-ng-model="row.entity.column1" style="width:95%">'
```

You do not use `{{}}` within `ng-` related syntax as it already parses it as angular:

[Fixed Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Ox1ArQQ3adHDtwsbXpJ?p=preview)

Comment: Yes.. Thank-you very much.  1 Question, why does it work initially?

Comment: I don't know enough about the internal workings of UI Grid but I'd assume there is a different set of code that fires on initial bind vs the code that fires when you change a variable tied to the grid. In your case the variable in question is the `grid.appScope.columnOptions` property.